# Dispersion Paint

Tags: painting, paint

Should I paint my apartment using a white dispersion paint?

What kind of finish would it have, do dispersion paints leave a plasticky surface as seen in some hospitals and schools please?

My dispersion paint is certified according to EN 13300.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it leaves a very plastic-like finish.  They are mainly used in areas that will be sprayed - like a hospital, school, public building.  There is nothing wrong with putting this in you home but I offer three pieces of advise.  Please test the color after using this on a small sample.  And #2 after using this you will have to hit the walls with a heavy primer if you ever want to go back to another color or change the look.  #3 - when you use this it is harder to replicate the look.  Meaning if you get a big scratch in your wall or have to remove a piece of wall and redrywall it is not easy to match your paint + dispersion coat.  That is why a lot of places will only do this with white.

Comment: Given that it sounds like it's a waterproof membrane...any concern about creating a second vapor barrier in some situations?